Django не видит .pgpass в корне пользователя
Я пытаюсь подключить postgresql к django в согласии с документацией. Как я понял, файл .pgpass должен находится в корневой директории пользователя. Но django не видит его там.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'service': 'my_service',
            'passfile': '.pgpass'
        }
    }
}

Это выводит ошибку "RuntimeWarning: Got an error checking a consistent migration history performed for database connection 'default': connection failed: connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"
При этом если укажу путь к пользователю 'passfile': '/home/user/.pgpass', то все работает нормально.
Вопрос: как сделать чтобы не нужно было указывать путь до пользователя (/home/user/)?
Использую vscode.
Права через chmod 0600 ~/.pgpass выдал.

Пока что решил через 'passfile': os.path.expanduser('~/.pgpass'),. ('expanduser' заменяет '~' на путь к директории текущего пользователя)

а если вообще не указать passfile? Предположу, что django проверяет параметр и если это не абсолютный путь, то добавляет путь до предполагаемого, например к корню проекта https://stackoverflow.com/a/71436097/10983392

Это тоже сработало. Причем .pgpass так и лежит в корне пользователя, а не в проекте. Благодарю.
